# Single point of truth for database shared by multiple applications

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've three application which share the same database. All three applications are built with php (Laravel framework). At the beginning there was only one app, so I've managed my database with the built-in migration feature from Laravel (modifying/creating/deleting tables and rolling these changes back). This way it was possible to track all changes in my version control.

Now, as I have three apps, I wonder where I should manage my database. Where is my Point of Truth? As I see, I have multiple options:

- Using one app as "database-master". Only this app must change the structure of the database. All other apps only have access to read/write data.
- Every app makes its own changes. This would result in a huge chaos as a rolling back / rebuilding from zero would be nearly impossible.
- Using a third party tool (e.g. MySQL-Workbench) to edit my DB. Seems like a valid option to me as this tool is built to handle databases and their structure/data. But is there some kind of version control? Can I roll back changes I've made?
- Using a fourth application (in my example another Laravel-app). This app is only responsible for the database. This way it would be possible to track all changes in git.

It's the first time I come across this problem and would be happy to gather some information about best-practices.

**Edit**
The applications share the same tables.

Comment: This question I feel is too broad and is going to be primarily opinion related. But I'd like to understand if the applications share the same tables, and if they do, why are there three interfaces to the same data?

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes they share the same tables and no, they aren't three interfaces to the data.